# jpa creating new entity while deleting old one that has the same unique key

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have entity zika1

```
public class zika1 {
@Id
int id;
String sika;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn
List<zika2> zikas=new ArrayList<zika2>();}
```

and entity zika2

```
@Table(name = "zika2", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "b" }))

public class zika2 {

@Id
String a;
@Column(unique=true)
String b;}
```

and this method:

```
    public void testuniqu()
{

        zika1 zik=super.find(1);

        zika2 zik22=new zika2();

        zik22.setA("karkar");
            zik22.setB(zik.getZikas().get(0).getB());
            zik.getZikas().remove(0);
            zik.getZikas().add(zik22);
            super.save(zik);        
    }
```

this throw a unique constraint exception but actually i am deleting the first entity . so jpa(eclipse link) not running this operation in the same db transaction.
is there a way to tell jpa to run the delete before the insert operation for the new zika2 entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is a normal flow, because EclipseLink doesn't execute commands *in order* you write it. So you need to tell EclipseLink some **hint**, that "delete" operation should be the first one. According to :
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Unit_of_Work_API_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_the_setShouldPerformDeletesFirst_Method_of_the_Unit_of_Work, you should use **setShouldPerformDeleteFirst**.

Comment: According to wiki article, you should do it on UnitOfWork. I think that entityManager should expose accessor method for it

Comment: You can also force the statement order in JPA using em.flush().